# Достаточно ли этих знаний чтобы устроиться на Junior Java?

Tags: java

Достаточно ли пройти два этих курса по Java чтобы устроиться хотя-бы Junior? И что изучать потом?

1. http://www.specialist.ru/course/dzhv1-a
2. http://www.specialist.ru/course/dzhv2-a

Comment: Проверил на своей IDEA — тоже не воспроизводится.

Comment: @NickVolynkin а у меня магическим образом заработало, хотя ничего не делал. Магия...

Comment: ясно. Хорошо. Тогда правильно сделали, что удалили вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

Текст не мой, нашел на другом форуме, но я считаю это вполне точное описание нужных знаний для Java Junior. В общем, эти вещи наверняка спросят на собеседовании:

1) Типы в Java, inboxing, outboxing, как примитивы друг в друга преобразуются.

2) Коллекции, иерархия интерфейсов и реализаций, чем ArrayList «лучше» LinkedList. Обязательный вопрос по HashMap-ам, что такое хеш-функция, внутреннее устройство.

2.5) Строки очень часто спрашивают, циклы, управляющие структуры, что появилось в JDK 7 по сравнению с 6-й. На 8-ку еще мало кто перешел.

3) Интерфейс, Абстрактный класс, 3 принципа ООП, несколько шаблонов проектирования.

4) Servlet, JSP, JSTL, Tomcat или другой Servlet container, никуда не девается жизненный цикл и как это все работает.

5) Advanced топики для джуна: системы контроля версий Git, Svn, системы сборок Maven, Gradle, Spring, Hibernate, Web-Service-ы (обычно REST), не зверствуют, но жирный плюс.

6) Иногда, чтобы завалить спрашивают про устройство памяти, что такое стек или куча, куда создаются объекты, зачем нужен garbage collection, параметры запуска JVM так что почитайте [JVMS](http://docs.oracle.com/.../jvms/se7/html). Почему завалить? Потому что этого как ни странно не знают многие middle/senior не говоря о джунах.

7) Базовый SQL, подзапросы, что такое сущность->связь, спроектировать 2 таблички и выполнить по ним запросы. noSQL также могут спросить.

8) Из веб-разработки иногда попросят базовый JS и CSS. HTML и так все должны знать. Хорошо если знаете основные типы HTTP запросов, в чем их предназначение и отличие.

9) JDBC, куда ж без него, раз в 2-3 года когда ходите по собеседованиям приходится вспоминать как это вручную создать connection, запихать statement, preparedstatement, вычитать данные в result-set, пробежаться по нему, закрыть connection.

10) Многопоточность обязательно спросят, как работает wait, notify, notify all, почему нельзя использовать sleep, как создать dead-lock, вокруг чего бывает синхронизация. Эта тема очень важна, т.к. спрашивают на каждом собеседовании, но чаще всего на проекте либо нормальная реализация из пакета concurrent, либо вообще не сталкиваетесь.

11) Что такое static-методы и переменные. Простейший пример из фильма 9-я рота. Белоснежка — статическая public переменная, а прапор — статический public-метод.

12) Потоки ввода вывода, базовые вещи, прочитать строку из консоли, какие бывают фильтры.

13) Английский крайне важен для аутсорса.

P.S. желательно что-то слышать про TDD, JUnit.

Comment: это кажется не только Java Junior. Это и на Java Senior потянет если это все в практике использовать. Это как я понял, для аутсорсеров. А Full-time программист и аутсорсер отличаются по требованиям. Но ОТЛИЧНАЯ СТАТЬЯ

Comment: Ну наверно у разных кампаний могут быть разные требования, но знать это все лишним не будет :)

Answer (score 3):

Как преподаватель могу сказать что это самый минимум.

Это просто теория. А в практике у Вас будет сложнее, так как не всегда задачи ставятся конкретно с ответами. Так что,

по практике знаю: Человек обучается 8 месяцев основы программирования. Потом делает разные проекты и в третий год, после усердной работы, может сказать что он Junior программист.

Так что, могу посоветовать изучить

1. Основы алгоритмов (что такое Алгоритм и чем его едять)
2. Основы языка. В вашем примере Java (синтаксис, как работает, ошибки и исправления и др.)
3. Взять любой маленький проект и сделать ВДВОЕМ. (Вам нужно научиться работать в команде!!)
4. Сделать 2й проект самостоятельно.

Теперь вот можете сказать что вы хотите быть Junior Programmer